# How to call a rest api from spring-xd

Tags: spring-xd

I am new to spring-xd and would like to understand is it possible to invoke an external rest api from springxd. My rest api expects a `request header` for `GET` requests and request header+message body for POST requests.
How do I invoke the URL ?

In my understanding http-client is to be used, but I am not very sure how do I use it.

I havent written any stream for this case yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `url` and `httpMethod` properties in the stream definition

`http-client --url=http://... --httpMethod=GET`

You will also have to set the `mappedRequestHeaders` to pass any custom headers that have been set up upstream.

```
--mappedRequestHeaders=HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,myHeader1,myHeader2
```

However, if you want to use uri variables...

```
url=http://somehost/foo/{bar}/{baz}
```

you will need a custom `http-client` module to add `<uri-variable/>` child elements to the outbound-gateway.

You will also need a custom module if you want to add headers to be mapped (via a `<header-enricher/>`).